# Get list options from jQuery UI autocomplete with url

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My element is a jQuery autocomplete element that gets its options from a URL:

```
$element.autocomplete({
    source: '/mysearchurl',
    open: function () {
        //...
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {
        //...
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //...
    }
});
```

It works as expected: The user enters some characters, and it displays the matching values in a drop-down.

What I want now, in my Javascript, is to get the options out of the list, ideally as the same JSON that it gets from the URL. I could try to collect them from the element through something like this:

```
$($element.data('ui-autocomplete').menu.element[0].list.childNodes).each()
```

But maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Why not using `$.getJSON()` (or `$.ajax()`) to get the datasource and then pass it to `source` property of your autocomplete widget?

Comment: It's a search field that triggers a search on the server. The source is not static. I could do the same search to get the same results in a different part of the code, but I'd like to avoid the unnecessary ajax calls.

Comment: So, using a function as a source could help (see http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). Inside the function you could do ajax call, and in the response callback you could keep JSON obtained from backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function with an Ajax call inside:

```js
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var el = this.element;
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/qnhcd",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var selection = data.filter(function(item) {
          if (matcher.test(item.value)) return item.value;
        });
        el.data("source", selection);
        response(selection);
      }
    });

  }
});

$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "autocompleteresponse", function( event, ui ) {
 refreshList();
});

refreshList = function() {
  var source = $("#autocomplete").data("source");
  console.log("refreshList", source);

  $("#list").empty();
  if (source) {
    for (var i in source) {
      $("#list").append("<li>" + source[i].value + "</li>")
    }
  } else {
    $("#list").append("<li>No options</li>")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">
<br>
<button onclick="refreshList()">
refresh list
</button>
<br>
<ol id="list">
</ol>
```

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/svLsw13f/